# How should I handle users who are developing phishing sites?

Tags: support, phishing

I found, in a chat where I am active, a user who was advertising his *new* phishing site. I flagged and kick banned the user from the chat, but I have still the impression that I should have taken more action. What do you think?

Comment: I've reported the site at: https://safebrowsing.google.com/safebrowsing/report_phish/

Comment: Thank you for sharing that link I have to bookmark it.

Comment: "Nuke him from orbit. that's the only way to be sure!" - Ellen Ripley

Comment: Not much you can do SO wise more than flagging as you did - thanks for that. The message is now deleted and right now I don't see a need for any other action. Of course - if they persist or otherwise show untoward behaviour then flag again and we'll review it.

Comment: @JonClements, Cerbrus - together, your comments form an answer. I'd like to see the link that Cerbrus gave as an answer, so that it will be preserved here on Meta - and updated when necessary. Would either of you write this as an answer? (Obviously I could do it myself, if you want - if you don't mind me "stealing" the comments).

Comment: For a Ms report you need to use IE( Yes, the cure is worse than the disease) Click on Menu(Gears), Security, Report Unsafe Website.

Comment: @S.L.Barth no objection from me - help yourself.

Comment: rekire, I rolled back your edit, because "a user" is correct: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105116/is-it-a-user-or-an-user

Comment: @Tom thank you for the hint, gamma is one of my weaker fields.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If you see this happen, there are two actions to take.

1. Flag the user, as Jon Clements points out in his [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347783/how-to-handle-users-which-are-developing-phishing-sites?noredirect=1#comment464846_347783).
   When you're the Room Owner, you can also move the message to one of the trash rooms, to negate its exposure until the flag is handled.
2. Report the site, [as Cerbrus did](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347783/how-to-handle-users-which-are-developing-phishing-sites?noredirect=1#comment464838_347783).

   - To report the site to Google, go to https://safebrowsing.google.com/safebrowsing/report_phish/
   - To report the site to Microsoft, use Internet Explorer, click on Menu (the gear icon in the top right corner) -> Security -> Report Unsafe website 
     ([Credit to Pierre Lebon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347783/how-to-handle-users-which-are-developing-phishing-sites/347787#comment464851_347783)).

As Lundin points out in a [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347783/how-to-handle-users-which-are-developing-phishing-sites/347787?noredirect=1#comment464935_347787), you could also alert the police - if the police force in your country has a department dealing with cybercrime. (Or the police force in the country where the phisher operates, assuming you can reasonably identify it.)

Comment: Might be worth adding that until the flag is looked at - if the message is hanging about for a bit then RO's can move it to one of the trash rooms to negate its exposure.

Comment: @JonClements Edited that in, thanks!

Comment: @JonClements so it is fine to (re)move the message? I was skeptic regarding the aspects of proof security.

Comment: @rekire until it can be deleted (which requires a mod or suitable number of abusive flags) - it's fine to move it from plain sight.

Comment: Umm... why would we report to _Google and Microsoft_ that a site is trying to steal sensitive information from you, for unclear purposes? Report crimes to the police instead.

Comment: @Lundin Search engines have a lot more influence on which sites users see as "safe" than the local police department does.

Comment: @blackorchid You don't say! That does however not deal with the criminals themselves. Also, mentioned companies are the true masters at phising...

Comment: @Lundin The one does not exclude the other. I've updated the answer a bit. Alerting the police of cybercrime is a good idea, if one has access to a police force that deals with cybercrime.

Comment: Last time I called my local police station to report my stolen bike they said they don't care. Is cybercrime higher on their priority list?

Comment: @rene You'd have to ask them, not me... FWIW The Dutch police does have it on their [website](https://www.politie.nl/themas/cybercrime.html#alinea-title-hoe-pakt-de-politie-cybercrime-en-gedigitaliseerde-criminaliteit-aan), including a piece about reporting it, at the bottom of that page.

Comment: @rene I once reported an eBay seller that scammed me and a couple of other people out of a €100 to my local police (not expecting much to come from it), and to my surprise a few months later I got an invitation to attend the court case. (The scammer and victims were in the same country, so that probably made things much easier.)

Comment: @m69 the skeptic/unbeliever in me needs a link to the case documents... I want to believe, but...

Comment: @Braiam Seriously? That's a bit... sad.

Comment: @Braiam You know you've been on SE for too long when people tell you a story and you're like, "Where is that documented? Where's the canonical reference?"   :-)